# Is the limit $\lim_{t \to 0} \left(t^2\ln t , t, \ln(t^3)\right) $ defined?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Find the limit or prove that it doesn't exist
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \left(t^2\ln t , t,  \ln(t^3)\right) $$
I got
$$(0,\space 0, \space -\infty)$$
does this mean the limit is defined ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: L'O Hopital on first. The remaining two are trivial.

Comment: didnt ask that thought

Comment: @PopularPower I want to know that whether the limit is defined if theres a - $\infty$

Comment: yes if $\lim _{x\rightarrow x_{0}}f\rightarrow \infty $ the limit exist and its inf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon the definition we are referring to.

A first issue is with the limitation $t>0$ which is usually implicitly assumed in order to deal with values within the domain of the function, that is for $t\to 0^+$.

The second issue is about the definition for not existence and usually we consider three main cases

- limit exists finite $L \in \mathbb R$, i.e. the function converges
- limit exists infinite $L =\infty$ (or $L =-\infty)$, i.e. the function diverges
- limit doesn't exist otherwise